# Change a list of associations by applying a function to specific keys?

Tags: associations

If I have a list of associations (`listAssoc`) with members all having key `someKey`, how can I generate a *new* list of associations `listAssoc2` that is equal to `listAssoc` except the values of `someKey` have all been changed by having some function `f` applied to their values?

Answer (score 8):

```
MapAt[Sin, #, "somekey"] & /@ listAssoc
```

Comment: If you modify the third argument of `MapAt` then you won't need to map a pure function: `MapAt[f, ascList, {All, Key[someKey]}]`

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query). Using a variation of @kglr's example:

```
ascList = Table[
    <|a->RandomInteger[100], "someKey"->RandomInteger[100], c->RandomInteger[100]|>,
    5
]
```

> {<|a -> 32, "someKey" -> 16, c -> 90|>, <|a -> 77, "someKey" -> 28, 
>     c -> 82|>, <|a -> 39, "someKey" -> 70, c -> 66|>, <|a -> 21, 
>     "someKey" -> 79, c -> 32|>, <|a -> 66, "someKey" -> 16, c -> 4|>}

Then:

```
Query[{"someKey" -> foo}] /@ ascList
```

> {<|a -> 32, "someKey" -> foo[16], c -> 90|>, <|a -> 77, "someKey" -> foo[28], 
>     c -> 82|>, <|a -> 39, "someKey" -> foo[70], c -> 66|>, <|a -> 21, 
>     "someKey" -> foo[79], c -> 32|>, <|a -> 66, "someKey" -> foo[16], c -> 4|>}

In m_goldberg's deleted answer, he suggests a nice refinement:

```
Query[All, {"someKey" -> foo}] @ ascList
```

> {<|a -> 88, "someKey" -> foo[78], c -> 98|>, <|a -> 2, 
>     "someKey" -> foo[18], c -> 24|>, <|a -> 52, "someKey" -> foo[8], 
>     c -> 64|>, <|a -> 7, "someKey" -> foo[96], c -> 73|>, <|a -> 92, 
>     "someKey" -> foo[75], c -> 49|>}

Comment: @m_goldberg I liked your answer, so I included it. If you undelete your answer, I would be happy to remove my addition.

Answer (score 3):

```
ascList = Table[<|a -> RandomInteger[100], someKey -> RandomInteger[100], 
   c -> RandomInteger[100]|>, 5]
```

> {<|a -> 44, someKey -> 93, c -> 67|>,
>    <|a -> 49, someKey -> 44, 
>     c -> 85|>,
>   <|a -> 61, someKey -> 4, c -> 88|>,
>    <|a -> 38, 
>     someKey -> 24, c -> 8|>,
>   <|a -> 78, someKey -> 87, c -> 44|>}

```
Normal @ Dataset[ascList][All, {Key[someKey] -> foo}]
```

> {<|a -> 44, someKey -> foo[93], c -> 67|>,
>   <|a -> 49, 
>     someKey -> foo[44], c -> 85|>,
>    <|a -> 61, someKey -> foo[4], 
>     c -> 88|>,
>   <|a -> 38, someKey -> foo[24], c -> 8|>,
>    <|a -> 78, 
>     someKey -> foo[87], c -> 44|>}

Also

```
MapIndexed[If[#2[[2, 1]] === someKey, foo@#, #] &, ascList, {2}]
```

> same result

```
MapIndexed[If[#2[[1, 1]] === someKey, foo@#, #] &] /@ ascList
```

> same result

Answer (score 3):

Use `Part` assignment:

```
listAssoc2 = listAssoc;
listAssoc2[[All, Key[someKey]]] = f /@ listAssoc2[[All, Key[someKey]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since V 13.1 we can also use `ReplaceAt`. To demonstrate its usefulness I create a list with a missing value:

```
  list =
   {<|"a" -> 32, "b" -> 16, "c" -> 90|>, 
    <|"a" -> 77, "b" -> Missing[], "c" -> 82|>, 
    <|"a" -> 39, "b" -> 70, "c" -> 66|>, 
    <|"a" -> 21, "b" -> 79, "c" -> 32|>, 
    <|"a" -> 66, "b" -> 16, "c" -> 4|>};

ReplaceAt[x_?NumberQ :> x + 10, {All, "b"}] @ list // Dataset
```

[image]

To get the same result with the "classical" `Query` - method we would have to write:

```
Query[All, <|#, "b" -> If[NumberQ[#b], #b + 10, Missing[]]|> &] @ list // Dataset
```

Additional `Condition`s can be injected easily:

```
ReplaceAt[x_?NumberQ /; Between[x, {1, 30}] :> x + 10, {All, "b"}] @ list
```